# Is there any way to 'preview' an item in the Recycle Bin?

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-explorer, recycle-bin

I often want to see files (usually code or other plain-text files) I've deleted so I know whether I want to restore them or not, the issue is you cannot see contents of recycled files unless you restore them.

Some times I've already created a new file with the same name in the previous location and I still want to peep in the erased file.
Furthermore, if the file I want to take a look into is inside a deleted folder, there is no real way I can see it!

So my question is if there is any way (programmatic way counts too) to access ALL the recycled files in deleted folders, and see their contents without restoring them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an interesting question so I decided to take a look at it, im glad you said programmatic way count, also this will only work with plaintext files and source code files.

1. Enable Explorer to show operating system files and well as hidden files.
2. Copy the explorer path for C:\$Recycle.Bin\Recycle Bin, it will look something like this

   C:\$Recycle.Bin\S-1-5-21-2188403881-3684878113-998817761-1001
3. Open PowerShell and use the Get-Content cmdlet to view your files, you will see the contents of the file in PowerShell.

I will post more detailed instructions, with screenshots, when I get a chance but I have tested it and it works.

Comment: Sounds great. I'd develop some sort of program that does it, but that will have to wait until I have some free time (which I don't)...

Answer (score 1):

Was in  the same situation  - dragged the file onto a usb stick and opened - but this wasa simple .xml file
Assume it would work for all file types

Comment: So, basically your answer is “Restore (undelete) the file, so you can look at it.”   This might be dismissed as a statement of the obvious, and not really an answer to the question, except for the fact that you contribute a piece of information that might not be widely known, namely, you can use drag-and-drop from the Recycle Bin to restore a file to a directory other than the one it was deleted from.   This answer should clarify that fact.

Answer (score 0):

Quick workaround, go to:

**View --> Extra large icons**

I know it isn't the same as preview pane. However, it provides quiet good preview without tweaking Windows. In many situations good enough for choosing files to restore or delete them forever.